# Using Shell to run a batch file after saving files in a new drive

Tags: excel, vba

I've a workbook that uses a macro to run a batch file (CEA.bat) via the Shell function. I created the workbook on my local D: drive (C: is the main/OS partition), and it works there.

I'd like to share copies of the workbook with my colleagues, but the shell function only seems to work in the drive in which it was created (D:). If I create a copy of the workbook under another directory in the original drive (D:), it works. If I create a copy in another drive (e.g. C:) or on another machine, the Shell function will not run the batch file.

The batch file and workbook are always saved in the same folder. The batch file works if I run it directly, so I don't think there's an issue with it. The issue seems to be related to the Shell function. The relevant lines of code are shown below:

```
Dim CEArun As String

ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path 
ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path

CEArun = Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CEA.bat" & Chr(34)

Call Shell(CEArun, vbMinimizedNoFocus)
```

I've come across a way to run batch files in VBA using the WshShell object, but I haven't tried it yet. It seems like it would only work if the "Windows Script Host Object Model" is activated. My colleagues have even less VBA knowledge than I do, so I'd prefer to give them a tool they can use without having to mess around with VBA settings.

Comment: Remove both `Chr(34)` from your code, when you declare a variable as `String` it already has the `""` so you are actualy telling `Shell ""C:\Folder\Cea.bat""`

Comment: Thanks Damian, I was a bit confused about the correct use of quotation marks in VBA. Unfortunately, removing them didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me,

Saved a .txt file with a ping to my own machine and run this code in my workbook. The bat openned and did the ping:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim MyPath As String: MyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CEA.bat"
    Shell MyPath, vbMinimizedNoFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Damian, this worked perfectly! I guess the issue must be related to the "Call" statement.

Comment: @seutmatt it shouldn't be a problem, not a good practice, but not a problem.